# Masonry Error: Bad masonry element: null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-masonry, masonry

This is the error I got from console. I'm using angular.js for this website, but I'm hoping I could just use the regular `masonry.js` without `angular-masonry`.

```
Bad masonry element: null
q()masonry....min.js (line 9)
a = null
c = Object { columnWidth=200, itemSelector=".item"}
d()masonry....min.js (line 9)
ui.js()
```

JavaScript:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});

var msnry = new Masonry( '#container', {
  // options
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
   <div id="container" class="list-container tiles-column-wrapper">
      <div class="tiles-column item ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $routeSegment.$routeParams.artifactId === artifact.artifactId}" ng-repeat="artifact in artifacts | orderBy:'-postedTimestamp'">
      <div class="tiles-column item ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $routeSegment.$routeParams.artifactId === artifact.artifactId}" ng-repeat="artifact in artifacts | orderBy:'-postedTimestamp'">
      <div class="tiles-column item ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $routeSegment.$routeParams.artifactId === artifact.artifactId}" ng-repeat="artifact in artifacts | orderBy:'-postedTimestamp'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post an example showing your issue.  The reason someone probably made angular-masonry is because a directive was probably needed which is common with jquery plugins.

Comment: Having the same problem without jquery and no angular. How did you solve it?